how to run forgejo(gitea fork) action on commit to repository without adding it to said repository?
I do have my work project (build with gradle) in it's own repository.
I also have my own forgejo (gitea fork) server on my local server. I also have runner configured.
I want to actions on on every commit to local server.
I can't just add files to .forgejo/workflows/my_action.yml I shouldn't add unnessary things to main work repo.
Is it possible to do such thing? how?

Please add more detail. How your projects and server are configured, what you've tried so far (specific steps, not just "I did x"). Use the EDIT button to improve and clarify your problem.
